# Bijective function between natural numbers and arrangements with repetition

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Assume I have a set **S** = {a, b, c}

I can then list all possible arrangements with repetition from set **S** as:

```
()
(a)
(b)
(c)
(a,a)
(a,b)
(a,c)
(b,a)
(b,b)
(b,c)
(c,a)
(c,b)
(c,c)
(a,a,a)
(a,a,b)
and so on...
```

Now, I am looking for a bijection from these arrangements to the natural numbers. For example:

```
()      <->    0        (0-tuple)
(a)     <->    1        (1-tuples)
(b)     <->    2
(c)     <->    3
(a,a)   <->    4        (2-tuples)
(a,b)   <->    5
(a,c)   <->    6
(b,a)   <->    7
(b,b)   <->    8
(b,c)   <->    9
(c,a)   <->   10
(c,b)   <->   11
(c,c)   <->   12
(a,a,a) <->   13        (3-tuples)
(a,a,b) <->   14
and so on ...
```

Is it possible to calculate this bijection in an efficient way? For example, if given (a,b,b,b,c,c,a) how could you calculate what natural number it maps to and vice versa?

**Edit**

This edit is in response to N. F. Taussig's comment.

Continuing with the set **S** = {a, b, c} as an example, the number of n-tuples for each n is 3^n. This means that:

```
          number of n-tuples    natural number mapping
0-tuple                0                  0
1-tuples               3           1  -   3
2-tuples               9           4  -  12
3-tuples              27          13  -  39
4-tuples              81          40  - 120
5-tuples             243         121  - 363
```

So that gets me part way there to my bijection. Just by looking at the chart I know that the tuple (a,a,a,a) maps to 40, and the tuple (c,c,c,c,c) maps to 363.

Now my problem is a bit simpler. I just need to know an easy way to number each n-tuple group.

Comment: A good place to start would be to figure out how many $k$-tuples there are for a fixed value of $k$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks. I edited my question considering your information. That gets me part way there, but I'm now stuck again.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe now I can just consider the tuple to be a number in radix-3. Then I just add the starting number for each n-tuple grouping. I think that might work.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I figured it out.

First, I can take each tuple and interpret it as a number written in base/radix of the cardinality of the set. For example, still assuming the set **S** = {a, b, c} I can convert the n-tuples into numbers using a=0, b=1, and c=3.

This means:

```
         base-3   decimal
()         0         0
(a)        0         0
(b)        1         1
(c)        2         2
(a,a)     00         0         
(a,b)     01         1
(a,c)     02         2
(b,a)     10         3
(b,b)     11         4
(b,c)     12         5
(c,a)     20         6
(c,b)     21         7
(c,c)     22         8
(a,a,a)  000         0
(a,a,b)  001         1
```

The problem is that (a), (a,a), and (a,a,a) all come out to zero. So I take this number and add to it the following:

$f(k) = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}3^{i}$

where k is the length of the tuple.

This means that:

```
         base-3   dec        f(k)     dec+f(k)
()         0         0         0        0 
(a)        0         0         1        1
(b)        1         1         1        2
(c)        2         2         1        3
(a,a)     00         0         4        4
(a,b)     01         1         4        5
(a,c)     02         2         4        6
(b,a)     10         3         4        7
(b,b)     11         4         4        8
(b,c)     12         5         4        9
(c,a)     20         6         4       10
(c,b)     21         7         4       11
(c,c)     22         8         4       12
(a,a,a)  000         0        13       13
(a,a,b)  001         1        13       14
```

And that's my answer. Thanks to N.F.Taussig for pointing me in the right direction.